# Flutter PopupMenuButton Remove splash and highlight

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if there is a way in which I can remove splash and highlight from PopupMenuButton
a bit like with other buttons.

```
new PopupMenuButton({
  ...
  splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
  highlightColor: Colors.transparent, // makes highlight invisible too
})
```

Answer (score 8):

[Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) Applies a theme to descendant widgets.

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: PopupMenuButton(...),
)
```

Comment: Note: might need to do a hot restart to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

Put `splashFactory` with `NoSplash.splashFactory`

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  ),
  child: PopupMenuButton(...),
)
```